# How to specify proxy in POM.xml file, no settings.xml file to be found

Tags: java, xml, maven, jenkins, proxy

I'd like to run a set up a jenkins job on a slave I have set up, weird thing is that there is no {MAVEN_HOME}/conf/settings.xml file to be found, so I can't specify the proxy there.

How can I specify a proxy in my pom.xml file, so I can get around my compnay firewall. Any help or guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried manually copying a fitting settings.xml to where it seems to be missing or reinstalling maven on the machine? I don't think adding proxy settings to the pom.xml is possible or a good idea.

Comment: It should be possible, I think I've done something similar but I don't remember...

Comment: The [Maven project descriptor reference](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.3/maven-model/maven.html) doesn't mention a `proxy.` The [Settings reference](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Proxies) does.

Answer (score 2):

The [Config File Provider Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin):

> *Adds the ability to provide configuration files (i.e., settings.xml for maven, XML, groovy, custom files, etc.) loaded through the Jenkins UI which will be copied to the job's workspace.*