# Set proxy for Maven in pom.xml (not in settings.xml)

Tags: maven, proxy, repository, pom.xml

I need to set an HTTP proxy for Maven to access repositories.
However, due to the given environment, I cannot set the proxy in the Maven settings.xml file.

So I am wondering if I can set the proxy in the project pom.xml file (or anywhere else in the project or mvn command).

Is this possible and, if so, how? Thanks!

Comment: Info: I have seen this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31620839 However, I am not able to use Maven plugins

Comment: Simple answer: proxies can not being set in in the pom file https://maven.apache.org/pom.html you have to use the `settings.xml`...

Answer (score 2):

OK, I got it:

One can call Maven with a **custom settings.xml**: `mvn -s settings.xml ...` and have such a custom settings.xml (e.g. next to the pom.xml) with e.g. the following content for proxies:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <proxies>
   <proxy>
      <id>proxy_http</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>proxy.example.com</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>example.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
   <proxy>
      <id>proxy_https</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>https</protocol>
      <host>proxy.example.com</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>example.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
</settings>
```